# File in TFS ist just gone?

Tags: tfs

How is the following screenshot even possible?

[image: How can this be?]

TFS seems to have "lost" the source-file "IFeedbackAjaxService.cs": While the file's history clearly indicates it should be there, the SourceControlExplorer denies its existence.

I already tried the usual steps: Reboot my machine, reboot the TFS and check on other developer's machines. The file is still gone everywhere.

Any ideas what I can do to fix that?

Edit: A better version of the image can be found here: http://imgdump.nl/hosted/8626229a041edef10ae3d3cf9609c93b.png

Comment: I would start by opening Tools/Options/Source Control/Visual Studio Team Foundation Server, and checking "Show deleted items in Source Control Explorer"

Comment: Did that already as you can see at the second icon from the left in the top of the screenshot. I just also rechecked the options as you described and found the checkbox in checked state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried showing deleted items? (Ie. if someone has checked in a delete of that file it will not show unless you ask team explorer to show more.)

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It's the second icon from the left in the top of the screenshot.

Comment: Please find a better version here: http://imgdump.nl/hosted/8626229a041edef10ae3d3cf9609c93b.png